# Ruby on Rails devise http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/sign_out gets routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

routes.rb =>

```
Sendemail::Application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users

    get "user/index"

    get "home/index"

    root :to => 'home#index'
end
```

rake routes =>

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)         {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)     {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)           {:action=>"cancel", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)             {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
       user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/confirmations"}
   new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format) {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/confirmations"}
                         GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)     {:action=>"show", :controller=>"devise/confirmations"}
              user_index GET    /user/index(.:format)             {:controller=>"user", :action=>"index"}
              home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)             {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}
                    root        /                                 {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}
```

When i type rails server i get this message every time =>

```
/home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/backports/uri/common_192.rb:53: warning: already initialized constant WFKV
```

For "http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/sign_out"

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
```

What should i do to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice how your routes say /users/sign_out is a DELETE request. Most browsers do not make DELETE requests by default. Just going to that URL would be a GET request to /users/sign_out.

This [how to add sign out links](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-sign_in,-sign_out,-and-sign_up-links-to-your-layout-template) should help you get it working.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but how can i get rid of this message ? /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/backports/uri/common_192.rb:53: warning: already initialized constant WFKV

Comment: I think that is unrelated to this question.

Comment: Yes, that may be unrelated, but how can i solve it ? Should i start a new thread for that ?

Comment: I think it would be best as a new question, if one doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 3):

Add `:method => :delete` to your signout link.