# Rails correct way to use link_to with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting started with rails and devise for authentication and I want to make a link to sign out when a user is logged into the admin page.

What is the correct way to write the `link_to code`

Here's my `rake routes`:

```
admin_index        /admin/index(.:format)         {:controller=>"admin/home", :action=>"index"}
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        {:action=>"cancel", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
              home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)          {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}
                    root        /                              {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}
```

I tried `<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path %>` but when i click the link it gives me the error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails devise http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/sign_out gets routing error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704130/ruby-on-rails-devise-http-0-0-0-03000-users-sign-out-gets-routing-error)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From this [devise sample application](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise/blob/master/app/views/layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb), recommended on the [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Example-Applications):

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li><%= link_to 'Edit account', edit_user_registration_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method=>'delete' %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: So i just need the `:method => :delete` since it's a delete method rather than a post method? Is that true for all links to a delete method?

Comment: yes, you are right, always use `:method => :delete/:put/:post` for your RESTful routes.

Comment: link to sample application is broken

Comment: @RomanPushkin Thanks, I've updated the code to a new example which works in the same way and isn't from a dead repository

Answer (score 1):

the root error of your problem is that you haven't use RESTful routes in your "link_to".

you should correct your code to:

```
<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

so that it will match the routes

```
DELETE /users(.:format)  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations" }
```

Comment: What do you mean i haven't used restful routes? Almost all of those routes were generated from te devise gem.

Comment: ok my mistake. I corrected the confusing text. you should call the 'link_to' in a RESTful way, (with parameter 'method')